# Create Android Widget inside App

Tags: android, android-widget

I'd like to link to my app widget configuration activity from inside my app. I know it's possible to launch the Android widget picker but can I bypass that step and let my users create a widget on their home screen from inside my app?

Answer (score 0):

> can I bypass that step and let my users create a widget on their home screen from inside my app?

No. For example, the user's home screen may not support app widgets (Android TV, Chrome OS, specialty home screen implementations, etc.).

Comment: People who create launchers surely have to have access to the machinery required to do these things, what makes them different?

Comment: @ZachSperske: They are the home screen. You are not, by your own admission ("let my users create a widget on their home screen"). You are certainly welcome to allow the user to pick an app widget (I think that's by launching an activity with a certain `Intent` action, though I'm not 100% certain). In principle, if you are using `AppWidgetHost`, you could arrange to have this chosen app widget appear in *your* app. What you *can't* do is hack into the home screen and somehow arrange for *it* to show this app widget.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clearing that up! Sad day, I wish Google hadn't abandoned widgets and was still improving them. Most people have no idea how to even add them, less than 0.1% of our 200,000+ users are using the widgets I've created.

Comment: @ZachSperske: I wouldn't describe it as "abandonded". They still work, and there are plenty of things in Android that are truly abandoned. I agree that Google has not done much with them in recent platform releases. However, even if they were busily adding app widget functionality, I would be stunned if they allowed app developers to force app widgets onto the home screen. They could offer a standard `Intent` for asking the home screen to prompt the user to add an app widget, but it would be ages before most home screen implementations would honor that `Intent`.

Comment: Perhaps abandoned was a bit strong, but yeah I would love an intent like that and they could give the makers of other launchers a kick in the pants by adding support to the Google Now launcher. Of course, I realize it's unlikely we'll see that happen.